# Cloning whole blog ends in 404

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am currently developing a `WordPress` project on a Windows machine (XAMPP) with my partner on a Mac (MAMP).

I installed WordPress on my local `/htdocs`, edited themes etc.
At the end of this all, I exported my WordPress database through PhpMyAdmin for my partner to install the whole project on his machine.

He has the `/wordpress` folder and imported the SQL with correct database names etc.

But whenever he goes to `localhost:8888/wordpress` it results in a 404 page not found error.

why?

Comment: Reset the Permalinks. It's usually this. Also, you will likely need to redefine the base URL - http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL#Changing_the_Site_URL

Comment: Why not just use [Duplicator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/)?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, there are a lot of serialized things in the wordpress database, what you can not just find / replace.

I moved from localhost to production a ton of times wordpress sites.
So what you need to do is to:

- Dump the database from local
- Copy the files to production server
- Import the database, but do not open the site in browser!
- Download the script from **[here](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/)**.
- Unzip, and upload this into a `wp-replace` directory
- Go to http://example.com/wp-replace/
- Follow the instructions. Replace the olddomain.com to newdomain.com/wordpress (do not use http and trailing slash, add port if needs)
- Go to the dashboard, login, and refresh the permalinks.
- Done

Comment: What should I search and replace when both machine run the project on `localhost`?

Comment: And both of them has port 8080, and both of the machine the wp in the wordpress directory??? If on your machine is `http://localhost/`, and your client has `http://localhost:8080/wordpress/` then you should replace `localhost` to `localhost:8080/wordpress` It's not just about domain.